# How to reference an array from one ruby script to another

Tags: ruby

Can we reference an array from one ruby script to another and access array elements?

for example : my first rb file

## 1.rb

```
$joe = "one"
$po = "two"
$so  = "three"
names = [ $joe, $po, $so ]
```

second rb file

## 2.rb

```
require "1"
$trial = names[1]
puts $trial
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `names` as a global variable, though I'd only recommend it if this is a small script. Else, a `Module` is the way to go, like in @Tempus's answer.

Example:

`1.rb`:

```
$joe = "one"
$po = "two"
$so  = "three"
$names = [ $joe, $po, $so ]
```

`2.rb`:

```
require "1"
$trial = $names[1]
puts $trial
```

Comment: In ruby 2.2.0, I need to include this line at the begging of the file to load 1.rb
$LOAD_PATH << File.dirname(__FILE__)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this ( Ruby 1.9 ):

**1.rb**:

```
module Whatever
    @names = ["one","two","three"]

    def self.names
        @names
    end
end
```

**2.rb**:

```
require_relative "1"

Whatever.names.each {|n| puts n}
```

Comment: Didn't know about `require_relative`, this could be useful. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, ever since 1.9, `.` is no longer in the load path.

Answer (score 2):

`names` is a local variable. If you want to access it from outside you have to define and access it

- in a module,
- as a global variable, using `$names`,
- as an instance variable, using `@names`,
- as a class variable, using `@@names`,  or
- as a constant, using `NAMES`.

In case of such a simple script a global or an instance variable should be perfectly enough.

Comment: You forgot the option of a constant (namespaced in a module or not).